# Why can't HAProxy connect to my local server when my browser can?

Tags: macos, nginx, haproxy

I'm on Mac OS. When I go to `http://localhost:8085` in my web browser I see my Nginx server working correctly but my backend configured like:

```
frontend api_gateway
    bind :8080
    mode http
    default_backend nginx

backend nginx
    mode http
    server nginx localhost:8085
```

When going to `http://localhost:8080` I'm getting the error:

## 503 Service Unavailable

No server is available to handle this request.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was due to Nginx listening on `127.0.0.1` which is an IPv4 address but HAProxy was connecting on `::1` the IPv6 address.

To fix it I changed the line from

```
server nginx localhost:8085
```

to

```
server nginx 127.0.0.1:8085
```

Although another option would be to configure Nginx to listen on IPv6 as well.